How to model pixel shot noise
I'm interested in modelling the effect of shot noise on images.  When taking a picture with a camera, the number of photons incident upon each pixel during the exposure time is (I believe) a Poissonian random variable $n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$, with $\lambda$ proportional to the local light intensity.  However, the grayscale value of a pixel is not $n$, but instead something like $\lfloor n / C \rfloor$, where $C\gg 1$ is some number that depends on how efficient the camera is at light collection.  That is, $n$ gets binned in forming the pixel grayscale value.
What is a reasonable way to model this distribution of pixel grayscale values?
Edit: To clarify, I'm not looking for general advice about modelling camera noise.  I'm looking to understand the particular model I've described above, of a binned Poissonian variable.  What is the distribution?  How can I understand it better?

I guess this question would be a better match to other forums in stackexchange.
Nevertheless, I guess this may be a good illustration of why domain knowledge is important for doing any statistical modeling. The model should fit the situation, so you have to consider the underlying physics and the design of the capturing device.
The detection limit of a camera is at extremely large numbers of photons. You may therefore safely ignore relativistic effects.
It is much more convenient to think in terms of incident power than in individual photons. Each sensor has a certain response curve (grayscale as a function of incident power). Different Sensors with similar CMOS design of the same manufacturer can be directly compared if we simply correct for the area per pixel. This response has an (approximately) linear regime, but excessive nonlinear parts at very low and at very high power. By controlling the exposure time, the photographer ensures that power * time = energy ends up in the linear part of the curve.
You can then also correct for inhomogeneity over the sensor area. For real pictures, this inhomogeneity is what forms the image. For lab tests, where plain white areas are sometimes photographed, you will often see “vignetting”, I.e. the corners appear darker. This is an effect of the design of the lens. Another thing to correct for.
To make it worse, you have to consider that color cameras pretty much always have a Bayer filter. Each pixel on the sensor is either green, red or blue. A lot of interpolation is used to assign a full RGB value to each pixel in the output image file.
And then there is compression. If you photograph in jpg format, some of the information will be thrown away by the compression algorithm. Also the in-camera electronics typically apply sharpness and contrast adjustments which further obscures the power vs. grayscale relation.
But, if you have all this, it gives you the signal.
The you want the noise.
Cameras are designed to be robust in terms of the signal generation. So, the variance in the chain from incident power to grayscale value on your computer monitor will be negligible.
The noise you see when you zoom in on dark areas is due to thermal effects. Incident light excites electrons, and the sensor is designed to collect these electrons. This gives rise to a static charge in each pixel, and that is transformed into a grayscale value.
Now, as it turns out, some electrons get excited due to thermal effects. The camera registers this charge as “false positives”; it is misinterpreted by the camera as “light hitting the sensor”.  You can easily try it out: take a picture with the lens cap attached.
Try changing the ISO value when you do this. There is an electronic amplification circuit that changes the result with different ISO settings. Also this circuit introduces noise, which further complicates matters. Depending on the particular model of the camera, you will have a different amplifier. Manufacturers strive for “ISO invariance”. That means they try to make it so that putting the ISO lower (which gives you a darker picture) and then adjusting the brightness in post-processing, gives the same result than putting the ISO higher and immediately taking a picture with proper brightness. This is a major selling point for serious cameras - you will not find information about how the manufacturer achieves this; they guard their secrets.
There are, however, physics models that describe the sensor-thermal-noise process. I am familiar with models describing this for photovoltaics, I have never looked at CMOS sensor models but I know they exist.
Whether the result you have is dominated by thermal noise or by the noise from the amplifier, depends on the particular camera you use.
I guess it should be clear this model is a major undertaking. If you just have some measurements you want to analyze, you are probably better off figuring out the signal/noise ratio and ensuring you measure in a regime where noise is low. Then you can treat it as a reproducibility effect, just like you would do for any other measurement.
Tip: measure in tiff or raw format. That at least avoids the jpg compression.
